# How do I select random rows in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

```
mytable

pid name field
=== ==== =====
1    A1   0
2    A2   1
3    A3   1
4    A4   0   
5    A5   0
```

This is my table structure. Here I want to select randomly 4 rows so I use RAND() mysql function in my query
my questions is

How do I pair to rows. I mean, I wanna select pid 2 and 3  always one ofter another.
I need in bellow order. **i don't want to break the pair A2 A3**

`A1 A2 A3 A4` or `A2 A3 A4 A1` or `A2 A3 A4 A5` or `A4 A5 A2 A3` and etc

I used the query below but it's not working for me

```
SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY RAND() ASC limit 0,4
```

Comment: it must help...once u get an array then u can shuffle whatever u needed? may i paste code for that

Comment: You mean you don't want to break the rows where field = 1? or is it really about the name column?

Comment: yes your right i don't want to break **field = 1** column .. i also like to get number of pairs any idea please post

Comment: Use a stored procedure. Ordering by RAND() is very slow even on indexed columns and is not a good practice. This is a question without an answer since i've been looking for ages (without PLs)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

turbod was close with his answer, he was just ordering randomly, when it seems you wanted to order by pid, after getting the random rows you wanted in conjunction with the ones concerning A2 and A3:

```
(
    SELECT *
    FROM `mytable`
    WHERE 
        name ='A2' OR 
        name ='A3'
    LIMIT 2
)
UNION
(
    SELECT DISTINCT *
    FROM `mytable`
    WHERE 
        name !='A2' OR 
        name !='A3'
    ORDER BY RAND( ) LIMIT 2
) 
ORDER BY `pid`
```

Comment: this would keep the A2 and A3 always in 1st and 2nd rows

Comment: No it wouldn't, actually. If A1 was also selected, it would come first through the second query in the Union, it would come before A2 and A3. That said though, if he wanted A2 and A3 to _always_ be in the second and third position, with random rows both preceding it and following it, then admittedly my query would have to be modified to use two unions, selecting a random row first, then A2 and A3, and then another random row afterwards, and just limiting the random selects to 1 row, and making sure the second random select doesn't use the same value as the first one.

Answer (score 6):

Generally, using ORDER BY RAND() is not a good idea. Please read the text by Jan Kneschke, showing why: http://jan.kneschke.de/projects/mysql/order-by-rand/

Answer (score 2):

I ran a heavy test on this, passed.

```
(
SELECT * , 0.5 AS ordercol
FROM `mytable`
WHERE `name`IN ( "A2", "A3" )
LIMIT 2
)
UNION (
SELECT * , rand() AS ordercol
FROM `mytable`
WHERE `name` NOT IN ( "A2", "A3" )
LIMIT 2
)
ORDER BY ordercol, `name` IN ( "A2", "A3" ) , `name` ="A3"
```

This will do the job very well. But to make the result even more random, execute that statement with replacing that 0.5 value in 1st line with a random value chosen by your client application code like `mt_rand(0, 1000000) / 1000000` in PHP . Make sure it falls between 0 and 1. But do **NOT** use mysql function `rand()` in place of that 0.5 because it will make A2 and A3 apart from each other. *The trick is assigning a random value for "ordercol" in all rows but keep it same for A2 and A3*

EDIT:
I believe we can replace the 0.5 value with a LEFT JOIN even instead of relying on discrete value by PHP, as we replace the first segment of the union, so the whole query becomes:

```
(
SELECT mt1.* , mt2.ordercol AS ordercol
FROM `mytable` AS mt1
LEFT JOIN (

SELECT RAND( ) AS ordercol
) AS mt2 ON TRUE
WHERE `name`
IN (
"A2", "A3"
)
LIMIT 2
)
UNION (
SELECT * , rand() AS ordercol
FROM `mytable`
WHERE `name` NOT IN ( "A2", "A3" )
LIMIT 2
)
ORDER BY ordercol, `name` IN ( "A2", "A3" ) , `name` ="A3"
```

Answer (score 1):

I doubt there is a sane way to this in MySQL only.

I can think of one way of doing it, assuming you are using PHP/MySQL:

Essentially you query everything but A3, then put A3 next to A2

```
$res = mysql_query("SELECT name, field FROM mytable WHERE name <> 'A3' ORDER BY RAND()");
$res2 = mysql_query("SELECT name, field FROM mytable WHERE name = 'A3'");

$data = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
      {
      array_push($data, $row);

      if ($row['name'] == "A2")
          {
          $row2 = mysql_fetch_array($res2);
          array_push($data, $row2);
          }
      }
```

Now $data will contain your results in the desired order.

Comment: This is an awesome solution in PHP. Nice job.

Answer (score 1):

If you are always selecting all the rows in the table:

```
SELECT pid, name, field, idx
FROM (
    SELECT pid, name, field,
        @pos := IF(name = 'A3', @idx, @pos),
        @idx := @idx + IF(name = 'A3', 2, 1), idx
    FROM mytable, (SELECT @pos = -1, @idx := 0) dm
    WHERE name <> 'A2'
    ORDER BY RAND()
)
UNION SELECT pid, name, field, @pos + 1 idx
FROM mytable
WHERE name = 'A2'
ORDER BY idx;
```

If you are not always returning all the rows, thus need to check if `A3` was returned to know if `A2` should be included:

```
SELECT pid, name, field, idx
FROM (
    SELECT pid, name, field,
        @pos := IF(name = 'A3', @idx, @pos),
        @idx := @idx + IF(name = 'A3', 2, 1), idx
    FROM mytable, (SELECT @pos = -1, @idx := 0) dm
    WHERE name <> 'A2'
    ORDER BY RAND()
    LIMIT 4
)
UNION SELECT pid, name, field, @pos + 1 idx
FROM mytable
WHERE @pos != -1 AND name = 'A2'
ORDER BY idx;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT name FROM mytable
  WHERE name <> 'A2' AND name <> 'A3'
  ORDER BY RAND()
  LIMIT 0,2
UNION 
  SELECT DISTINCT name FROM mytable
  WHERE name = 'A2' OR name = 'A3'
  ORDER BY name
)whateverQueryAlias
ORDER BY RAND()
```

That should do it.

Comment: your query says **Incorrect usage of UNION and ORDER BY** error

Comment: Oh, and I found another error. The last ORDER BY RAND() could break the A2 A3 combo. Got some other things to do right now. Will come back later and think about it a bit deeper.

Comment: any suggestion i'm dying to know

Comment: What else do you use beside MySQL? PHP? It would definitely be easier to do that in any programming language. I wonder if it is even possible just using SQL. And, sorry, I don't have the time right now to figure this out.

Comment: This query, even with the error fixed, will always have A2/A3 as the last two results...

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

```
SELECT *
FROM `mytable`
WHERE name ='A2'
OR name ='A3'
LIMIT 2
UNION
(SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM `mytable`
WHERE name !='A2'
OR name !='A3'
ORDER BY RAND( ) LIMIT 2) ORDER BY RAND()
```

Comment: As in the case of tombom answer, your query always returns A2 and A3 as the first results, that is not what the OP asked for.

Comment: well... now you're reshuffling everything, so A3 is not guaranteed to be after A2

Answer (score 0):

SELECT *, RAND() "xrand" FROM yourtable A ORDER BY xrand LIMIT 4

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT * FROM `mytable` order by rand(), name asc limit 4.
```

i think this will satisfy your need.

Comment: what wrong in this..? i tried and then only i posted this one.

Comment: @Sakthi: This selects four random values from the table. Read exactly the question: the OP wants to have "A3" always after "A2", condition that your solution does not consider at all.

Comment: i read that question and also i tried for the same example brother. i am getting the output. if u given the name asc means., u will get the output surely.

Comment: @Sakthi: nope, it doesn't work. Your solution does not necessarily select A3 and it will always order the elements in an ascending order, it will never, for instance, return `A8, A2, A3, A1`, or `A2 A3 A4 A1` which are valid outputs.

Comment: one small request., try the same code vat i given there. becoz, i tried more than six times now. its working. one more dont use and between the rand() and name. just use ,(comma). if there is any mistake., tell me. thanks for your feedback.

Comment: @Sakthi: I tried it, and I got, for instance `A4, A1, A6, A2` and `A6, A2, A7, A3`. (note that you need to add a few lines to the table if you want this to be really meaningful) (using MySQL v14.14)

Comment: what those lines..? and u didnt get the correct result brother..?

Comment: For sure, sometimes it works, but not always. Your second order by clause (name) will only be used in case of ties in the first one (rand), ties which cannot happen. So having the second order by clause is useless. I don't know how else to convince you, if not creating the table and running your own query...

Comment: oh..! now i get your point. thanks for your guidance brother.