# How to efficiently get a random row out of a massive table?

Tags: mysql, sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I select random rows in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5104141/how-do-i-select-random-rows-in-mysql)

Okay, so I have a table storing game data, and it's reaching 7 million rows.

I need an efficient way to select a random row.

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
SELECT `id` FROM `information` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1;
```

Fairly logical query. Takes *8 seconds to run*. Completely unacceptable.

Second attempt:

```
SELECT FLOOR(RAND()*COUNT(`id`)) INTO @target FROM `information`;
SELECT `id` FROM `information` LIMIT @target,1;
```

Fails on syntax error with the variable in the second query.

Third attempt:

```
SELECT `id` FROM (SELECT `id` FROM `information`) `a` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
```

The idea here is to strip out all the other fields, since they're unnecessary bulk. It half-works, bringing the time down to 6 seconds. Still far too long, though.

And... I'm out. I can't think of any other ways (but it is 1 AM...), so any suggestions would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I will award a bounty to whoever can provide a solution that also lets me exclude a given set of IDs (example: `WHERE id NOT IN (1,2,3,4,5)`)

Comment: this question don't deserved to be downvoted. it is hard to get random record speacially dealing with millions of record `+1`

Comment: I also fail to see how this is a duplicate of the other question.

Comment: It isn't. (And if anything, that one should be closed as a duplicate of this one. Yeech.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using `INNODB` engine, an article I read before suggested that it is better to count the number of records first using `COUNT(*)` because the engine does not cache the count of the table unlike `MyISAM`,

```
DECLARE @count INT;
DECLARE @offset INT;

SET @count = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `information`);
SET @offset = CONVERT(FLOOR(RAND() * @count), SIGNED);

PREPARE mystatement FROM "SELECT `id` FROM `information` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT ?, 1";
EXECUTE mystatement USING @offset;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE mystatement;
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/90b1f/2)

*DISCLAIMER*: the query i used performed exactly as needed on 3m records. I don't know how it behaves on 7m records though.

Comment: Interesting. This would certainly work.

Comment: how long did it take? `:D`

Comment: Actually I went with a different solution, taking advantage of using PHP to do essentially what this does. I accepted this answer because it's a pure MySQL version of what I ended up doing. The new solution takes about 1-2 seconds, which is slow but much more acceptable (especially since it's for something loaded in AJAX on the side, not the main content)

Comment: Your question is tagged sql, mysql and query. You ended up using PHP. Feels like you didn't ask the right question...

Comment: @Khez I edited the tags. I don;t know that he was using PHP that's why I didn't include it.

Comment: @JW I wasn't asking you to edit the tags :) I was trying to get Kolink to pay more attention to future questions he asks...

Comment: If you're using a random offset anyway, is there any reason to `order by rand()` at all?

Answer (score 1):

Could you generate the random number first? Assuming you only need one row,

SELECT (random number in range) FROM information